# How can i Get a Visual Editor for WinUI?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, winui

I'm looking for a way to use WinUI with a visual Editor, but can't find one. And i'm not sure where to start on writing my own.
As of today (December 11th, 2023), there is no Win UI Visual Editor like there was for WPF provided with Visual Studio. It doesn't seem like Microsoft wants to make it a priority, has anyone found a work-around/solution to this problem? Are there VS extensions available or would anyone know about how we could start writing such an extension?

Comment: The first thing I do when I start working in WPF on any new Visual Studio installation is turn of the XAML designer.

Comment: If you try to use WinUI for more than 5 minutes, it becomes painfully obvious that Hot Reload is not a solution to quickly design good-looking UI. It constantly breaks, especially when you are changing the structure of the layout (which you kinda have to do sometimes when you are designing). And when it does it takes too long to get back to the page that I am designing because now I have to go through the entire app to get there.

Comment: Did I downvote this question?  No.  I did not.  It takes a seriously awful question to make me downvote it.  This one is a pretty good question on what seems to be an important topic to people.  The only reason I mentioned turning off the WPF Visual designer is because I find it gets in the way much more than it helps.

Comment: I am a fan of the Visual Designer for WPF and think Win UI 3 seriously needs one. I don't use the drag and drop feature to build my UIs, I do most of the work directly in XAML. Where the designer comes in handy is being able to visualize my UI as I build it. MS states that Hot Reload should make up for the lack of the designer, but I disagree. Sometimes I am designing a reusable module or dynamically loaded control that doesn't have a dedicated window. Hot Reload would force me to build stub code that creates a window to host this control just to view it.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to get a WinUI Visual Editor, is to make Microsoft take this seriously.

Here is the link to the feature request:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Feature-request-Visual-designer-for-Wi/1608476?q=WinUI+Designer

Please Up-vote this feature. The fact that it isn't treated as mandatory by Microsoft is insane.